# Expressing negative values to be searched for in string array in VBA

Tags: arrays, vba, string, loops, range

The code below compare the values in range "B"&t to an array given in x(1). I also want to include negativ values so that negativ values in that range are detected as well when the comparison is done. I just dont know how to enter a "negativ value" in general in my array x(1). I have tried this "<0" but didnt work out well.

```
 sub compare()

 dim X(1) as string
 dim t as integer
 x(1)=("0")

 t=2
 Do

 If IsInArray(ad.Range("B"&t).Value,x) then
 'do something
 Else: 'do something else
 End if
 Loop Until ad.Range("A"&t)=""

 End sub     


 Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
 IsInArray=(UBound(Filter(arr,stringToBeFound))>-1)
 End Function
```

Comment: You have not declared your variable `t` and also not initialized it. So the value of `t` is zero. That means your range reference is invalid: `ad.Range("B"&t).Value` is trying to look at cell B0, which is undefined and will give an error.

Comment: Hi peter, i corrected it. Thnx for it

Comment: Well next, your array `X` really holds two values, indexed from 0. So the implied declaration is really `Dim X(0 to 1) As String`. If you only wanted a single value indexed from 1, then you'll have to explicitly declare `Dim X(1 to 1) As String`. Additionally, if you're expecting to compare strings against strings, then holding the "0" is fine enough. Just be aware though that implicit conversions to and from Strings to Longs will be occurring.

Comment: Hi peter, thank you for your advice. I use the array to compare the values in a cell to these values in the array. However, I dont know how to depict a "negative" value generally as to negative values in the cell are detected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**General "IsInArray" functionality**

A function "IsInArray" typically has to check, if a whatever typed element is part of an array.

Implementation with `Application.Match`:

- `IsInArray = IsNumeric(Application.Match(ToBeFound, WithinArray(), 0))`
- works with numbers and text (not case sensitive)
- compares full text, but accepts * and ? also
- If an element is part of the array, `Application.Match` returns its position (a number). If not, it returns a non-numeric error and therefore `IsNumeric` returns a `False`.

Implementation with `Filter`:

- `IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(WithinArray(), ToBeFound, True, vbTextCompare)) > -1)`
- works with numbers and text (selectable case sensitivity)
- always compares text parts, so "A" will be in array ("ABC", "DEF")
- If an element is part of the array, `Filter` returns a filtered array with the remaining items. As the remaining array is 0-based, the upper bound of the array will be at least 0. If the element is not part of it, then `Ubound` is not 0 or higher, therefore >-1 comparison.

---

**Example**

If single cell contents should be compared against a predefined array:

```
Private Sub CompareRangeValuesWithGivenArray()
    Dim ad As Worksheet
    Dim testArray() As Variant
    Dim t As Long

    Set ad = ActiveSheet
    testArray() = Array("0", -3.2, "ABC", 5)

    For t = 1 To ad.Cells(ad.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If IsInArray(ad.Cells(t, "B").Value, testArray()) Then
            Debug.Print ad.Cells(t, "B").Value & " is in Array"
        Else
            Debug.Print ad.Cells(t, "B").Value & " is NOT in Array"
        End If
    Next t
End Sub


Private Function IsInArray(ByRef ToBeFound As Variant, ByRef WithinArray() As Variant) As Boolean
    IsInArray = IsNumeric(Application.Match(ToBeFound, WithinArray(), 0))
End Function
```

(Keep the `IsNumeric` even if you search for text)

---

**Negative values**

If negative elements also should be returned as `IsInArray() = True`, then capsulate your "to-be-checked-values" by `Abs()` and put only positive values into your array:

```
If IsInArray(Abs(ad.Cells(t, "B").Value), testArray()) Then
```

If negative elements should be in your array:

```
testArray(1) = -1
testArray(2) = -2.5
```

or

```
testArray() = Array(1, -2.5)
```

Comment: I hope this explains the functionality you need. If so, please consider to mark it as answer as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). If not, don't hesitate to comment here.

Comment: I just dont know what the"-1" in the code "IsInArray=(UBound(Filter(arr,stringToBeFound))>-1)" stands for.

Comment: I have applied your code to mine as well as the whole private function part and it doesnt detect negative values as negative. The "Isnumeric" Code looks wheather it is numeric or not but not after the sign bevor the value. The array is suppose to detect all the values in the array plus all negative values. In other words, I want the "isnumeric" to exclude negative values

Comment: ... and now the comparison >-1 and the negative values are also explained :)

Comment: Hi Asger, Thank you very much for your effort and your help. Have advanced my knowledge